# How can I wire a RFID antenna to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, rfid

I try to connect [this](https://eccel.co.uk/product/rfid-ant1356m-65mm/) RFID antenna with a Raspberry Pi 4B:

[image]

What does TX1 and TX2 stands for?

How can I make this antenna work like this RFID module I am using from a starter kit, which can be seen in this picture:

[image]

A GPIO extension shield is available for this task if it makes things easier for wiring up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect the antenna to you Raspberry Pi.  It is an **antenna,** not an RFID transmit and receive module.

Look at the other picture that shows a complete module.  It has a chip that handles all the RF stuff, and communicates with the Pi over the SPI bus.

Your antenna has none of that.

Your antenna is just the part of the module with the big wire loops.

---

It is probably possible (with some really clever software, a few transistors, and some other bits and pieces) to make your Pi do what is necessary to drive the antenna and receive the RFID data.

It wouldn't be easy, and I know I couldn't do it.  Asked the way you have asked it, your question says you aren't up to it either.

Get an RFID module and move on.

Comment: So according to your answer, the second picture shows a RFID module with an included antenna. What I need for my RFID antenna is a RFID module without an antenna. I will look for this kind of module.